# using tesseract in ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, tesseract

I downloaded tesseract, and I want to use it in c++ code.
but I get these error:

```
TessOp.cpp:6:39: fatal error: tesseract-ocr/api/baseapi.h: No such file or directory
```

In my code I also use OpenCV, this is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <tesseract-ocr/api/baseapi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Load image
    cv::Mat im = cv::imread("1.png");
    if (im.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot open source image!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(im, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    // ...other image pre-processing here...
    //Mat binary_image;
    //threshold(gray,binary_image, 25, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    //imshow("binary_image",binary_image);

    // Pass it to Tesseract API
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess;
    //tess.Init("C:/Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/", "eng");
    tess.Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT);
    tess.SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_SINGLE_BLOCK);
    tess.SetImage((uchar*)gray.data, gray.cols, gray.rows, 1, gray.cols);

    // Get the text
    char* out = tess.GetUTF8Text();
    std::cout << out << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I put the file in samples folders in OpenCV directory,since I use OpenCV in the code; I run the file using this command :

```
g++ `pkg-config opencv --cflags` my_code.cpp  -o my_code `pkg-config opencv --libs`
```

Comment: I am facing same problem . let me know how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding the include directory of tesseract nor are you linking it.
Add the following to command line

```
-I/usr/local/include/tesseract -ltesseract
```